# How to use for loop in FEEL language in DMN Diagram by Enterprise Architecture

Tags: enterprise-architect, dmn

FEEL language is not fully supported by Enterprise Architecture. For example, for loop command in this language is not supported by EA.

```
for i in [1,2,3] return i * i
```

result:
[image]
[image]

Running Decision Validations ...
Validating Decision 'Decision' ...
Warning :  'Decision': Context Entry #1 : 'Expression can not be parsed. ' for i in [1, 2 , 3] return i * i''
Decision Results: (0) error(s), (1)warning(s)

Comment: Please explain clearly what the problem is. So what is happening now, and what did you expect to happen.

Comment: Oh, Deer look at this! The Gold Partner of omg (Sparx Systems) didn't implement FEEL Completely!

Comment: @GeertBellekens I edited the question and added the error message of ea

Comment: You probably should send a bug report for that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it just seems to be a product defect which should be reported to the vendor.

Comment: @Ghanat Well spotted. Sparx is a deer with one horn.